# How to get the Total Number of Tokenholders of ERC20 tokens?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, etherscan

Is there any simple API or datafeeds where I can just get the total number of tokenholders of ERC20 tokens?

Comment: Check https://etherscan.io/token/0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0#balances

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information from http://etherscan.io.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for GET tokens?address=0x... endpoint:

{
"address": "0x...",
"tokens": [{
    "address": "0xd26114cd6ee289accf82350c8d8487fedb8a0c07",
    "name": "OMGToken",
    "decimals": 18,
    "symbol": "OMG",
     "totalSupply": "140245398245132780789239631",
    "owner": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dead",
    "balance": 3412333140000000000,
}]
}

Example: https://api.ethplorer.io/getAddressInfo/0x24cc2359bc42b2c855678c7fae8efbb3a7d3660c?apiKey=yourkey

Answer (score 0):

You can get this info by checking the metric non-zero-balance-address https://studio.glassnode.com/metrics?a=USDT&category=&m=addresses.NonZeroCount

They have API support.